# import and export all .vue files from the folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm working on a VueJS project.

I have a folder with several single file components and I need to export all in one index.js

so I have this code

```
import a from './a.vue'
import b from './b.vue'

export {
    a,
    b
}
```

but I'd like to do this dynamically, so I do not have to change this index.js every time I create a new component

someone to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a library that does all this work, follow the link

### [named-exports](https://github.com/yungsilva19/named-exports)

Answer (score 1):

From [this article](https://dev.to/simo_benhida/tip---import-vuejs-modules-at-once-58dl), you could try this:

```
const requireModule = require.context(".", false, /\.vue$/); //extract vue files inside modules folder
const modules = {};

requireModule.keys().forEach(fileName => {

  const moduleName = fileName.replace(/(\.\/|\.vue)/g, ""); //

  modules[moduleName] = requireModule(fileName).default;
});

export default modules;
```